# nsdateformatter timezone issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
"2012-01-30 00:00:00 +0000",
"2012-01-31 00:00:00 +0000",
"2012-02-01 00:00:00 +0000"
```

I have a list of **dates** from xml listed above .i need to format and sort..i am using the code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];  
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd"];  
         [dateFormatter stringFromDate:d];
```

I am getting(jan 30,jan 31,feb 01)(india) and client getting in US location(jan 29,jan 30,jan 31)..

After that i update something and i set timezone..

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"]];  

dateFormatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]
                            autorelease];
```

i am getting wrong date(jan 29,jan 30,jan 31)....and i am searching some other sites and i am setting

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

This code works for me .i don't know this code works for other countries

I need correct date depends on countries...

Comment: I formatted your code for you. Please read the instructions on the edit page for next time.

Comment: @Rams enter the correct format string. Include identifiers for the time and time zone. Then you won't have any problem. Your issue is that you're only taking the month and day and truncating time and time zone. Use those and it will always be the correct day.

Answer (score 0):

Set the timezone for the date you parse. The formatter assumes GMT and the date you print assumes your local timezone.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```